# Can I apply a CSS class within an Angular 2 animation state?

Tags: angular

I am attempting to utilize Angular 2's animation facilities and I've discovered that I can't seem to be able to set a CSS class associated with a state, and I instead must hard code style values, like so:

```
@Component({
  animations: [
    trigger('responseState', [
      state('default', style({
        color: '#31708f',
        backgroundColor: '#d9edf7',
        borderColor: '#bce8f1'
      })),
      state('success', style({
        color: '#3c763d',
        backgroundColor: '#dff0d8',
        borderColor: '#d6e9c6'
      })),
      state('error', style({
        color: '#a94442',
        backgroundColor: '#f2dede',
        borderColor: '#ebccd1'
      })),
      transition('default <=> success', animate('500ms ease-in')),
      transition('default <=> error', animate('500ms ease-in')),
      transition('error <=> success', animate('500ms ease-in'))
    ])
  ]
})
```

What I was hoping to do would be something like:

```
@Component({
  animations: [
    trigger('responseState', [
      state('default', style({
        class: '.default-state'
      })),
      state('success', style({
        class: '.success-state'
      })),
      state('error', style({
        class: '.error-state'
      }))
    ])
  ]
})
```

Can anyone let me know if this is possible?

Comment: If you just want to apply classes to particular states, why use the animations API rather than binding to the elements?

Comment: I left out some things in the question, but I have some state transition animations which I am utilizing.  I will update the question to re-include them.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible. The angular animations API seems to still be pretty limited from my experience playing around with it. The only thing I've been consistently using it for is applying animations/transitions to elements that have unpredictable / varying heights. I still use standard CSS3 animations and transitions for nearly all my angular code.

Comment: So just to add to this; its using the Web Animation API so if anyone's similarly looking at this like I did "Why would I hard code CSS in TypeScript?" this is essentially why its setup this way.